# How can I find out which program creates a file/folder in my C: drive?

Tags: windows-7, monitoring

I am looking for an app that can monitor my C: (system) drive and find which program is creating a folder, with the rather generic name `TEMP1\`, on that drive.

I wouldn't mind if it could hook the creation of files too – as there a couple of files created as well (quite probably from another process). Google does not help me, as the names of those files are a bit generic too (not as `TEMP1` though – `dvmaccounts.ini` and `dvmexp.idx`).

The problem is that every time I delete those, they are recreated on startup, so the utility I'm searching must start up on boot and also start fast. It should also be really clever, as my C: drive is huge.

Comment: Why are you even worried about it? You do know that some programs actually *need* to create some files to work properly (even if they're improperly designed)?

Comment: @slhck : The edits you made are actually cutting out info - please revert. Not : for example TEMP1 - TEMP1, which means google is no help. And I am not (very - I have a couple of reasons to be) worried - rather curious. The folder is always empty btw. And admittedly I hate people dumping stuff fin my c: drive

Comment: I didn't quite understand, but does it make more sense now? I reverted the sentence to what you originally wrote. Please change as necessary. Sorry if it lost some info.

Comment: **Related for Mac visitors:** http://superuser.com/questions/69682/find-out-which-app-created-a-file

Comment: **Related for Linux Visitors**: http://superuser.com/questions/155299/finding-out-why-how-a-folder-is-being-created :)

Comment: `.ini` files are usually human-readable plain text files -- what's inside "dvmaccounts.ini"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), free from Microsoft, to do that. Set filter inside the Process Monitor to this folder, and it will show you when/if it is accessed:

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity.

If you think this folder is being accessed only during the boot process, you can enable **boot logging** by selecting the corresponding menu point under Options. When you boot Windows the next time, Process Monitor will log all system activity into a log file, which can be reviewed at a later time. You'll really need to enter a restrictive filter, otherwise your boot time will be really long.

Comment: Hmm - I know about process monitor - I will try that - still I would like to have an app that boots with  windows - cause I have the impression the folder is not being actually used.

Comment: Added info about boot logging.

Comment: Ahh - this - will be trying this on next reboot and let you know - I left PM open all night - my paging file exploded - I woke up with 4 kb in my c:\ lol - TEMP1 was not accessed though

Comment: Ok - the temp1 folder disappeared but thanks to PM I found where those files were coming from - DVMExportService.exe fromour beloved ASUS - marked

Comment: I haven't used Process Monitor before, could you tell me what the precise filter should be? "Path Is (FolderPath)"?

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete the folder. Change permissions so that only a specific account (different than the one you normally use) has access to the folder. That ought to throw a wrench in whatever processes is doing this, hopefully allowing you to catch it.

Comment: I might try this on next startup - still the folder is always empty - might be kind of a placeholder ? moreover I do need an app that can monitor and log dir/file creation - and I have already searched and tried and I have not one really up to the task