# A folder keeps appearing in C drive

Tags: windows-10

Can anyone tell me how to know the source of a folder named "viva" which contains a sub-folder named "SSL" ? this folder keeps appearing each time I delete it from my C: drive, can anyone tell me because of which app is coming back or even how can I bust this app?

Comment: Sounds like something unique installed or your system

Comment: You need to provide more information on what programs are installed on your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question here : [How can I find out which program creates a file/folder in my C: drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/348881/how-can-i-find-out-which-program-creates-a-file-folder-in-my-c-drive) .   Some program is creating that folder, and it's not necessarily a bad thing.  I don't know what C:\viva\SSL is, but Process Monitor can give you some info.